# Replace HTML string with javascript using .replace

Tags: javascript, html

I have this html code:

```
<p>Hello, this is a test replacing, <span class="myclass">over test</span> and <span class="myclass">over test</span>.</p>
```

My javascript works to replace the word "Hello" with "FuuBar".

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Hello/g, "FuuBar");
```

But I can not replace `<span class="myclass">over test</span>` by `<span class="thanks"><b>Thanks God</b></span>`

I am starting in javascript. I need to resolve this in pure js. Could help in my code? And sorry for the English.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puya3/) for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked quotations? You should escape them in the classname in JS or use single quotes. Please provide the code if that's not the case.

Other than that, replacing the whole body doesn't seem the best idea for a task like this.

Comment: Thanks mat and maxedison. You saved my life!

Answer (score 2):

Use the DOM for this. Check here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].classList.remove('myclass');
  spans[i].classList.add('thanks');
  spans[i].innerHTML = '<b>Thanks god</b>';
}
```